# How to access wcf service from another computer?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, tcp, wcf-data-services

I have a wcf service and i install it as windows service.
I can access this service from 192.168.2.6 machine:

```
"net.tcp://192.168.2.5:2025/Services/mex".
```

i want to access this service from another computer using static ip and port.

How can access this service ?

I tried to connect net.tcp://staticIp:port/Services/mex and i got error :

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://[staticIP]:[port]/Services/mex'.If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

(I navigate my [port] to inside port 2025)

my config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IServices" />
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.2.5:2025/Services" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IServices" contract="myServices.IServices"
    name="NetTcpBinding_IServices">
    <!--<identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>-->
  </endpoint>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="F8ShadowWcfLib.Services">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="F8ShadowWcfLib.IServices">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://192.168.2.5:2025/Services" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Edit1:

I remove  tag from config and i add it at runtime.

```
myService.ServicesClient myServ = new myService.ServicesClient();
            EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://[staticIP]:[port]/Services") ,
                                                EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("net.tcp://f8srv.f8.com.tr:2299/Services"));
```

myServ.Endpoint.Address = myEndpointAdd;

I got different error : The server has rejected the client credentials.

Comment: what error are you getting? Have you tried generating a proxy against the mex endpoint on your service?

Comment: i add my error to question.I didnt generate a proxy.Cant i access without generating proxy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow seperate connection set AddressFilterMode : Any
and set your identy both service and client side.

This article about identy settings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx

```
 [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
   public class Services : IServices
   {
        .
        .
        .
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably related to this part:

```
<identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
</identity>
```

This work work locally because localhost makes sense locally, but across a network it doesn't.

You can validate this identity in a number of ways, such as specifying the UPN (user principal name) of the user running the service, or an SPN (Server Principal Name) of the server running the service (although for this you'll have to register a SPN).

This article should explain it a little:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx

Comment: this article uses HttpBinding in example.I write this wcf service fot tcpBinding to use as windows service.Do i have to change tcpBinding to httpBinding to access accross a network ?

Comment: As high mentions, TCP works fine over the network. The main caveat really is that you have to make sure that your firewall isn't blocking the ports (in your case 2025).

Comment: I can access from remote computer with telnet , > telnet [staticIP] [port]... Also i try to access in local computer, > telnet 192.168.2.5 2025... Everything seems working...

Comment: Have you made the identity changes?

Comment: edited my question! i got error : The server has rejected the client credentials. I think i can write same identy name on server wcf config, right ?

Comment: I try to access to server from win7-form application , remote comp is win serv 2003 enterprise edition

Comment: I solved it !!! thx for identy idea but there is another setting.I added [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)] on top of my Services class, and it worked.